# Creating A Memory Tile Match Game with Phaser Framework....Various Problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, phaser-framework

To begin, my current problem is due to the fact that i want 2 cards arranged in a 6x4 format in phaser. From these, each tile would have 2 cards where one is a plain card with a letter and the other is the back end of the card (and all the cards would have these covering them). When i click, the cards are to reveal whats beneath and when they click another card and this matches, you score a point.

The array in which I stored the letters on cause the letters to show alright but rather than show 2 of each letter, it sometimes shows 4 of the same letter or sometimes just one or not at all given that i put just the right number of elements in the array to be shuffled and displayed on the cards.

Aside from basic HTML and scripting tags leading to my `main.js` and `phaser.min.js` (or `phaser.js` depending on how i saved the file) below lies the code:

```
    var game = new Phaser.Game(1000,750,Phaser.CANVAS,'gameDiv');

    var background_pic;

    var card_1;
    var CardStacks;

    var text;

    var card_back;
    var card_BackStacks;

    // var firstClick, secondClick;

    var score;

    // var myCountdownSeconds;

    // var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'];

var array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'];


var mainState = {

    preload: function() {

        // game.load.image('backgrounds', "assets/bg.jpg");
        game.load.image('Card_1', "assets/cards/plain.png");
        game.load.image('Back', "assets/cards/back.png");
    },

    create: function() {
        game.add.text(380, 10, 'Sun-Tiles', 
            {fill : 'blue',
            fontSize : '50px'
        });

        score = game.add.text(800, 30, 'Score: 0', 
            {fill : 'white',
            fontSize : '20px'
        });

        card_1 = game.add.sprite(0,0, 'Card_1');
        card_1.anchor.setTo(0);
        card_1.visible = false; //sets original tile invisible by default.

        card_1 = game.add.group();
        card_1.enableBody = true;
        card_1.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

        createTiles();

        text = game.add.group();
        // text.enableBody = true;
        // text.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

        // var score = game.add.group();
        // score.add(game.make.text(10,10, "Score: " + 100,  { font: "32px Arial", fill: generateHexColor() }))

        card_back = game.add.sprite(0,0, 'Back');
        card_back.anchor.setTo(0);
        card_back.visible = false;  //sets original tile invisible by default.

        card_back = game.add.group();
        card_back.enableBody = true;
        card_back.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

        // createBackTiles();

        // scoreText = game.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#' });
    },

    update: function() {
    }
}

// function countScore () {
// counting number of matches

//     //  Add and update the score
//     // score += 15;
//     scoreText.text = 'Score: ' + score;

// }

function createTiles() {
    for(var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            CardStacks = game.add.sprite(x*160 + 20,y*160 + 90,'Card_1');

            card_1.inputEnabled = true;

            var style = { font: "100px Chiller", fill: "blue", wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: 150, align: "center"}; //The style to be applied to the text on cards.

            Phaser.ArrayUtils.shuffle(array);

            text = game.add.text(0,0, Phaser.ArrayUtils.getRandomItem(array), style);
            text.x = 40; text.y = 20; //setting all the text to the right spot along the X and Y axis on the blank card.
            CardStacks.addChild(text); // making the text variable a child of the tile(blank card) variable. 

            // card_BackStacks = game.add.sprite(x*160 + 20,y*160 + 90,'Back'); //to reveal the unflipped cards
        }
    }

    tween.onLoop.add(descend,this);
}

game.state.add('mainState', mainState);

game.state.start('mainState');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every card, you shuffle your array of letters and pick a random one. This does not remove the element from the array, which means that for the next card, you can easily pick the same item by accident:

```
for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    // ...

    Phaser.ArrayUtils.shuffle(array);
    text = game.add.text(0, 0, Phaser.ArrayUtils.getRandomItem(array), style);
  }
}
```

Instead, shuffle the array *once*, before your loop. Then, in the loop, remove one element for every card to prevent duplicates:

```
var shuffledCards =Phaser.ArrayUtils.shuffle(Array.from(array));

for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    // ...

    text = game.add.text(0, 0, shuffledCards.pop(), style);
  }
}
```

Comment: ok this really helped! thanks a lot. if going to go onto the next step which is getting the clicks and checking if the cards match. if i hit a wall and help out there isnt helping then ill come back with a comment.